# ISNull, NULLIF, COALESCE, not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have an SQL query where i'm trying to return a "0" if the result is Null.

So far I have tried:

```
SELECT     NULLIF (Amountt, '0') AS count
FROM         1Table
WHERE     (Operations_Day BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (location = @Storenumber) AND (Hour = '18')

SELECT     ISNULL(Amountt, 0) AS count
FROM         1Table
WHERE     (Operations_Day BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (location = @Storenumber) AND (Hour = '18')

SELECT CASE WHEN (Amountt IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE Amountt END AS count
FROM         1Table
WHERE     (Operations_Day BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (location = @Storenumber) AND (Hour = '18')
```

All results return a BLANK string, which is not handled well in VB.net  How can I return "0"

Answer (score 0):

That means that `Amountt` is not `NULL`.  Try using a `case` instead:

```
select (case when Amountt is null or Amountt = 'NULL' or Amountt = '' then 0 else Amountt end)
```

If the situation is that your code is returning *no* rows, then you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amountt), '0') AS count
FROM 1Table
WHERE (Operations_Day BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND
     (location = @Storenumber) AND (Hour = '18');
```

Comment: it is null.  When I change it to a basic select statement, it returns "NULL"

Comment: I did just tag this is SQL Server 2000

Comment: Aggregation worked. Although, I'm not sure why.  It returns a "NULL" Value when the query is a simple select statement... any idea why?

Comment: @Shmewnix . . . The reason it worked is because your original query was returning no rows.  With no rows, there is nothing for the functions to operate on.  An aggregation query always returns one row (without a `group by`, that is).

Comment: Like I said, On a simple select query it returns 1 row (NULL)